# Get all files in FTP directory

Tags: c#, .net, ftp

I am new to C# and want to get list of file names in ftp directory. But i read some answer on other topics **WebRequestMethods** is for the single request. 
Here is my current code getting FTP object for a specific files.
I want all files ends with ".txt" and want regex like "*.txt". How can I get all file names
in FTP directory?

```
reqFTP = (System.Net.FtpWebRequest)System.Net.FtpWebRequest.Create(new Uri("ftp://95.0.181.84/bankToCompany/" + fileName));

reqFTP.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile;
reqFTP.UseBinary = true;
reqFTP.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(obj.ftpUserName,obj.ftpPassword);
System.Net.FtpWebResponse response = (System.Net.FtpWebResponse)reqFTP.GetResponse();

Stream ftpStream = response.GetResponseStream();
FileStream outputStream = new FileStream(obj.collectionFileDownloadAddress + renameAddress, FileMode.Create);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream);
 string contents = reader.ReadToEnd();
```

[How to: List Directory Contents with FTP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229716(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

FTP is an old and horrible protocol to work with even in .Net but MSDN has some documentaion about it [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229716(v=vs.110).aspx).

Check out the "How to: Download Files with FTP" and "How to: Upload Files with FTP" links to the left aswell if you need.